# Integration by parts or substitution for $\int x \cos (x^2) dx$

Tags: integration

With $$\int x \cos (x^2) dx$$ I can use substitution to solve this integral.

$$u=x^2, dx =\frac{du}{2x}$$
$$\int x \cos (x^2) dx = \int x \cos (x^2) \frac{du}{2x} = \frac{1}{2} \int \cos(u) = \frac{1}{2}\sin(u)=\frac{1}{2}sin(x^2)+C$$

But can't I also solve it with integration by parts and should get the same result?

$$\begin{array} \int x\cos (x^2) dx &= \frac{1}{2}x\sin(x^2) - \frac{1}{2}\int 1\sin(x^2)dx
\\
&= \frac{1}{2}x\sin(x^2) + \frac{1}{4}\cos(x^2)+C
\end{array}$$

Or am I mixing up things?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem in your integration by parts is that $$\int \cos(x^2) \,dx \neq \frac 12\sin(x^2)$$

And similarly, you *cannot* integrate $\sin(x^2)$ as you did.

In both case, you are implicitly treating $x^2$ as the variable of integration, i.e., you are implicitly treating it as you would treat $u = x^2$ and integrating with respect to $u$, except for the fact that your failed to accommodate $du = 2x \,dx \iff dx = \dfrac{du}{2x}\neq \dfrac{du}2.$

Answer (score 4):

$$\int \sin(x^2)\,dx \neq -\frac{1}{2}\cos(x^2)+C$$
$$\int \cos(x^2)\,dx \neq \frac{1}{2}\sin(x^2)+C$$
You can confirm that by differentiating the RHS.

Comment: Should be $-\frac{1}{2}cos(x^2)$ but that gets eliminated

Comment: I've just wanted to comment like this. The OP made lots of mistakes.

Comment: ah. now I see it.. That solves my question.

Comment: derivative of $x^2$ is $2x$ and not $2$